# Iterating a list of data frames through a function

Tags: r

I have written a function to strip down a data frame to contain only the columns I want to plot. I now want to iterate a list of data frames through that function, so that each individual data frame only contains the info relevant to my plot.

Here is the function:

```
clean_data <- function(show_df){
  show_data <- show_df[,c(1:2,7)]
  colnames(show_data) <- c("Week", "WeeklyGross", "AvgTicketPrice")

  #turns WeeklyGross into Numeric values
  show_data$WeeklyGross <- gsub('[^a-zA-Z0-9.]', '', show_data$WeeklyGross)
  show_data$WeeklyGross <- as.numeric(show_data$WeeklyGross)

  #turns AvgTicketPrice into Numeric values
  show_data$AvgTicketPrice <- gsub('[^a-zA-Z0-9.]', '', show_data$AvgTicketPrice)
  show_data$AvgTicketPrice <- as.numeric(show_data$AvgTicketPrice)

  show_data
}
```

And here is my code when I attempt to iterate the list of my data frames through the function:

```
df.list <- list(atw_df, cly_df, gent_df, kin_df, 
                        mo_df,on_df, van_df, war_df)
new_list <- list()
for (i in seq(df.list)){
  new_list <- clean_data(i)
}
```

I know that my loop is missing something, but I cannot figure out what. I want to store each data frame from that list in it's revised format as a variable so that I can use them to plot the information.

EDIT: made some code changes, I am now receiving an incorrect number of dimensions error in show_df[, c(1:2, 7)]

EDIT2: more changes made to the for loop, still receiving same error message.

Comment: Please provide the reproducible example.

Comment: Your function is not returning the subsetted dataframe. Try adding `show_data` after its last line. Also you shouldn't use `i` twice in your for loop. Create a new list and assign the new df to it.

Comment: Two more comments: 1. The error is because you're not sending the df to `clean_data`, you're sending just `i` (first, then you do it right) Remove the `clean_data(i)` line. 2. If you create the list inside the for loop you will erase it every time it's run. Create it outside and just add the clean dfs inside as a new element (`new_list <- clean_data(i)`).

Comment: @Molx still coming up short. Clearly I have alot to learn regarding for loop logic....

Comment: Use `for (i in df.list){` instead of the current. And even though I was trying to help you here, you should post some example data so we can check the results and post an actual answer. This edit/comment game isn't ideal.

Comment: Why do your `gsub` patterns leave alpha characters in the column? The call to `as.numeric` has a good chance of introducing `NA` values. Shouldn't the pattern be `[^0-9.]`?

Comment: Also `new_list <- clean_data(i)` will leave you with a single data frame in `new_list` - the cleaned version of `war_df`. You need to append to `new_list`, not replace it.

Comment: The error message suggests there aren't 7 columns in the data frames. Are your indices correct?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your function, and your list, simply do

```
new_list <- lapply(df.list, clean_data)
```

Which will call `clean_data` once for each data frame in `df.list` and return a list of newly cleaned data frames.

Thus your entire "loop" becomes

```
df.list <- list(atw_df, cly_df, gent_df, kin_df, 
                mo_df,on_df, van_df, war_df)

new_list <- lapply(df.list, clean_data)
```